# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (xenial) crashing after reboot / log out / suspend

Tags: 16.04, crash

Environment :

- Laptop (Latitude E5470) on a docking station
- Encrypted HDD
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- lshw -c video :

  - product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
  - vendor: Intel Corporation
  - version: 07

Rebooting / Logging out / Suspending leads to a crash.

Any suggestions? Really the graphic driver is the reason (its the newest version provided by Intel)?

**EDIT:**
Could it be any connection to the encrypted HDD?

on a quick skim, I noticed this in /var/log

```
amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
```

Installed are also the following packages :

- xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
- xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-lts-xenial

But why at all would they be needed?!?

**EDIT2**: They are not needed at all. I removed them, and the problems disappeared. But so strange, Ubuntu have installed them by default, even though there hadn't been any AMD graphics card.

Comment: well, from what you gave on information it could be anything? battery or powersupply for example. 
please supply us with /var/log/syslog , /var/log/dmesg , /var/log/Xorg.?.log and the likes.

Comment: also the title has trusty while your question has xenial, which is it?

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann : Is there any specific trace you are looking for?

Comment: I'm searching specifically for messages during the reboot right before 'it' crashes. BTW: what is crashing anyway?

Comment: What laptop model is it? Does it have a amdgpu as well?

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu is installed, but xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-lts-xenial not. However, why would Ubuntu need these amdgpu at all?

Comment: Ahh, sorry about this: I meant to ask of there is a GPU from amd in the laptop

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the /var/log/syslog, gave the hint for the crash:

```
amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[drm:amd_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!
```

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS preinstalls the following package

```
- xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
```

which seems to be a buggy installation, when no AMD graphics is available (In my case I have an Intel gprahics card).

I removed this amdgpu package via the Synaptic Manager. You could do it directly like

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
```

After it the problems disappeared.

So, a general approach would be:

1. Inspect your var/sys/ logs
2. Find out the error sources before the crash (in my case it was the amdgpu)
3. Remove the error source (In my case, I don't have any AMD graphics, so removing it was good. You might want to update to the right driver if available etc.)

Thanks to [@Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann](https://askubuntu.com/users/555486/phillip-zyan-k-lee-stockmann) for helping me to find this solution.

Comment: this is surprising, but I did exactly as you did and I still get the error. And the amdgpu package is definitely not there. BTW, it seems that there are drivers now for your amdgpu: https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx

Comment: @MarcCayuelaRafols ... a year later things might have changed